# Putting A Basic Switch In Front Of Several Basic Linksys Routers?

Tags: networking, router

We have a building with 10 individual offices.

We have a single internet connection coming in where our ISP has provided us with 10 public ip addresses.

Each office would like to have their own Linksys firewall router to manage their inbound/outbound port traffic.

Can I just put a basic switch in between the ISP service modem and the 10 individual linksys routers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. You'll just want to make sure that you keep track of which router has which IP address, and of course you'll want to configure them statically to avoid your ISP providing a particular business with an IP different than what they were using.

Comment: A managed switch with ARP spoof prevention or similar would allow you to lock down switch ports to a particular MAC and/or IP address.

Answer (score 5):

We do exactly this. We have an 8 port Siemens switch connected to the output of our ISP's Cisco router. Each port of the switch goes to a router in a different division of the company. I labeled each router with  IP info so ,that in the case of a router failure, a new router could be dropped in with minimal trouble.

Comment: what model number is your switch? any problems using an unmanaged switch here?

Comment: The switch is just a basic 8-port 10/100 switch. It's been running for about 3 years now with no problems at all. Didn't see the need to add complexity with a managed switch.